# Pairwise alignment of long string sequences

Tags: algorithm, alignment, dynamic-programming

I want to find the globally optimal (or close to optimal) pairwise alignment between two long (tens of thousands) sequences of strings, but the algorithm is expected to operate on any object sequences. 
I also want to use my own distance function implementation to compute the similarity of two objects. For shorter sequences, I could use the dynamic time warping (DTW) algorithm but the DTW algorithm needs to compute and store a n*m distance matrix (n,m are lengths of the sequences) which is not feasible for longer sequences. Can you recommend such algorithm? A working implementation would be a plus.

The following example clarifies what the algorithm needs to do:

```
Input:
Sequence A: i saw the top of the mountain
Sequence B: then i see top of the mountains

Result:    
Sequence A:      i saw the top of the mountain
Sequence B: then i see     top of the mountains
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know, if I understood your requirements right, but it sounds to me like you are trying to solve a [Stable Marriage Problem](http://athens.src.uchicago.edu/jenni/atbarbar/assignement_references/gale_shapley_AMM62_college%20admissions%20and%20stability%20of%20marriage.pdf). The original solution of Gale and Shapley in the link is in O(n*m) time and O(n+m) space, if my memory serves me right. The implementation was pretty straightforward. 
There are also some later solutions with different variants of the problem.

You also could try to solve this problem by using Maximum Bipartite Graph Matching, e.g. [here](http://www.mcs.csueastbay.edu/~simon/handouts/4245/hall.html), for getting a different optimality criterion. This also can be done in O(n*m).

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't explain my requirements good enough. What I'm looking for is an DTW-like algorithm that can be applied to long sequences. From Wikipedia: In general, DTW is a method that allows a computer to find an optimal match between two given sequences (e.g. time series) with certain restrictions. The sequences are "warped" non-linearly in the time dimension to determine a measure of their similarity independent of certain non-linear variations in the time dimension."

Comment: ahh, sorry for misunderstanding you. That indeed seems a little bit more difficult than stable marriage.